# Implemented Iterable hands wrong size back

Tags: java

I'm new to this site, so please feel free to correct me if there's anything wrong about my question or the style of the question.

I need to implement the Iterable Interface in my ShareCollection class, so that I can iterate over all the shares in this class. When I'm testing my class with the sample data it always hands back '0' as size, even though there are (in my example) two shares in my collection.

**Here's the code of the class + one sample method which hands back an error:**

```
public class ShareCollection implements Iterable<Share>{
    private HashSet<Share> shares;

    public ShareCollection() {
        this.shares = new HashSet<Share>();
    }

    public ShareCollection(Collection<Share> shares) {
        for (Share s : shares) {
            HashSet<Share> checkSet = new HashSet<Share>(shares);
            checkSet.remove(s);
            if (checkSet.contains(s)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("There can't be two shares with the same name!");
            }
        }
        this.shares = new HashSet<Share>(shares);
    }

    public boolean add(Share share) {
        if (share == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("share isnt allowed to be null!");
        }
        return shares.add(share);
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<Share> iterator() {
        return new HashSet<Share>(shares).iterator();
    }
}
```

**Here's the main method with the sample data I'm using:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Share s1 = new Share("s1", new ArrayList<>());
    Share s2 = new Share("s2", new ArrayList<>());

    ShareCollection sc = new ShareCollection()
    sc.add(s1);
    sc.add(s2);

    int counter = 0;

    for (Share s : sc) {
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.print("Counter: " + counter + "\n");
    System.out.print("Size: " + sc.size());

}
```

**Here's the output for the main-method:**

```
Counter: 2
Size: 0
```

**Here's the error for the 'add'-method:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: ShareCollection#size should give 1 for a collection with 1 elements.
Expected: <1>
     but: was <0>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at jpp.marketanalysis.tests.data.TestShareCollection.hasElements(TestShareCollection.java:158)
    at jpp.marketanalysis.tests.data.TestShareCollection.testAdd(TestShareCollection.java:55)
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

**Update:**

- Exchanged the ArrayList with a HashSet (see @SeanPatrickFloyd's first answer)

Comment: please share your test code

Comment: There is no `size()` method in the code that you posted?

Comment: @msandiford I don't exactly know what you mean, but in the main-method last row 'sc.size()' I use the size()-method

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd it's a JUnit-test to which I have no access sadly, I can just say that the exact same Error is handed back (with different size numbers) by the other methods, I just had hoped that it's 'obvious' what produces the error (like wrong use of the Iterable interface etc.)

Comment: Yes, but in the `ShareCollection` class you posted, there is no implementation of a `size()` method, so we can't see what that method does.

Comment: @msandiford I hope I get this right: I'm using the default implementation of the size() method in the main-method and this hand back the output 0, although there are 2 shares in my shareCollection. And the error says 'ShareCollection#size should give 1... but was 0'. I hope you understand my problem better now

Comment: There is no inherited implementation for `size()` for the declaration of class `ShareCollection` as you have posted it here.  Can you check that `ShareCollection implements Iterable<Share>` is the same as you have in your code.

Comment: @msandiford so, if I'm not 'overriding' or implementing a size() method, sc.size() will always hand back '0'? Well, then I didn't test my code right. Do you have any idea what could produce this error then?

Comment: @T.Mo it is a compilation error if you call a method that doesn't exist.  As I'm assuming you aren't getting a compilation error, there must be some difference between the code that you are looking at on your computer and what you have posted here.  Are you sure that `ShareCollection` isn't extending another class (eg `AbstractCollection`)?

Comment: This is all very strange. Maybe you're implementing some other `Iterable` class besides `java.lang.Iterable`?

Comment: @shmosel I'm not extending any other class, it is the exact same Code here, I just copied it from my computer. My main problem is the error that I posted last and this error is tested with a JUnit-test to which I have no access. The task description is: "The class should implement java.lang.Iterable in order to iterate over all shares"

Answer (score 0):

Possible error: Does your Share class override the `.equals()` method?
Because `ArrayList.contains()` delegates to `.equals()`

Also, I see at least two problems with your code:

- An ArrayList is very bad at a .contains() lookup (O(n)). You should use a HashSet instead (in that case you'd need to override both `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` in your `Share` class), it gives you O(1) and handles the .add() method properly for you as well
- The Iterator you are returning is the ArrayList's original iterator, which makes your code vulnerable in several ways, including `ConcurrentModificationException` if you add something while iterating, but also mutation, if someone calls `.remove()` on the iterator. I'd suggest you make a defensive copy of the collection and use that iterator.

Here's your code rewritten accordingly:

```
public class ShareCollection implements Iterable<Share>{
    private final Set<Share> shares;

    public ShareCollection() {
        this.shares = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public ShareCollection(Collection<Share> shares) {
        this.shares = new HashSet<>(shares);
    }

    public boolean add(Share share) {
        if (share == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("share isnt allowed to be null!");
        }
        return shares.add(share);
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<Share> iterator() {
        return new HashSet<>(shares).iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I generated equals and hashCode in the Share-class and overrode them both. I understand your concerns and changed the list to a HashSet, but unfortunately this don't fix the error.

Comment: @T.Mo again, there is the possibility of the test being faulty

Comment: There truly is this possibility, but I highly doubt it, cause all these tests where used several times (years) before. Well, I'm just trying anything to make it work, maybe I'm lucky and fixing the error by trial and error.